# How to check IDREFS length in xPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have the next `DTD` definition

```
    <!ELEMENT testNode EMPTY>
    <!ATTLIST testNode
          listOfNodes IDREFS #REQUIRED
          bestNode IDREF #REQUIRED
    >
```

when I get `/testNode/@listOfNodes` I have to check if there are more then one ref in **listOfNodes**. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple IDREF vlues in attribute listOfNodes, it must be separated by space as per DTD rules. So, you may follow this example to check multiple values:

```
let $x := <testNode listOfNodes="d1 d2"/>
return
  if(contains($x/@listOfNodes, ' '))
  then "Yes"
  else "No"
```

For multiple value it will return "Yes" otherwise "No"

Comment: thanks a lot. Does xPath have function that can convert IDREFS to list of Strings ?

Comment: With '("Yes", <p>{string-join(tokenize($x/@listOfNodes,' '),',')}</p>)' you may get output as 'Yes<p>d1,d2</p>', and to get output like 'Yes<p>d1</p><p>d2</p>' you should use '("Yes", for $IDREF in tokenize($x/@listOfNodes,' ') return <p>{$IDREF}</p>)'.